# Best practice: same button multiple functions depending on input

Tags: forms, buttons, web-app, input-fields

I have an input field where the user should enter a URL. If the url points to a sitemap (ie sitemap.xml) all the urls contained in the sitemap should be downloaded whereas in the case of a url not pointing to a sitemap, only the single url should be downloaded. I'm trying my best to keep the UI clean so I rather not mess it up with instructions etc but feel that without any instructions there is no way for the user to understand the sitemap bulk download feature. Any ideas? I did try two different buttons but felt it looked abit messy..

Answer (score 2):

Instructions aren't clutter if they're necessary to understand what the thing is doing, but depending on your circumstances, there are a couple of options (beyond just including a line of explanatory text) that come to mind: you could let the user decide whether to treat the file as a sitemap or not; or you could display a notice if the link looks like it points to a sitemap.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I'm really trying to keep the interface as minimalistic as possible. Maybe just use the placeholder for the input field and enter "Enter URL.. (sitemap.xml for bulk download)"?